# Blackberry Web works 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am interested Blackberry 10 development with HTML5/CSS, but I don't know what tools are needed for developing an application. Please explain the procedure to develop an application in Blackberry 10 using HTML5/CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the official documentation. It gives an overview of WebWorks, and the tools needed.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html

Use the Ripple emulator plugin for Chrome for testing:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_with_ripple_1866966_11.html

Beginner tutorial:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/tutorial_javascript_geolocation.html

Signing keys overview:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_your_app_1920008_11.html

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Scott's answer, I'd also recommend checking out our GitHub repo which is full of sample apps for you to use as reference.

https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples